# php, string value, length and integer value of a variable don't matche

Tags: php

I am getting a variable from a socket. After reading the respond I am trying to convert the value to a number. if I print the respond it looks correct however when I convert it to number using floor() it doesn't give me the right answer. I also tried to print the length of the variable and it is still not working as it suppose to: This one is for value :185

```
echo("**************** ".floor($res[0]));
echo "################### $res[0]";
echo "------------- ".strlen($res[0]);
```

output:

```
**************** 1################### 185------------- 12
```

I have also tried stripslashes, trim and also `ereg_replace('[:cntrl:]', '',$res[0])`

Comment: Sidenote: `ereg_replace` is deprecated.

Comment: I get: string(12) " 185"

Comment: I can see a character between " and 1, but length 12 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I saved the value in a file and opened the file using notepad++. I saw the following character in between my string:

```
SOH,NULL, and bunch of other non character values
```

What I am assuming is PHP automatically ignore the ASCII values are not show able on the screen (less than 21Hex).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following: [intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)($res[0])

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with:
     $res = (int)$reg[0];

Hope this helps.
Bye